# acf function and ggAcf function giving a different outcome

Tags: r, ggplot2, forecast

I was using the following code for analyzing a time series

```
require(tidyverse)
require(forecast)
frame <- scan("http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/fancy.dat") %>%
  ts(frequency = 12, start = c(1987, 12))
frame_auto_differentiated <- diff(diff(frame, lag = 12))
ggAcf(frame_auto_differentiated, type = 'correlation')
acf(frame_auto_differentiated)
```

and I receive the following outcome:
[image]

[image]

Is there any argument that I should change? I do believe the acf function is giving the correct outcome.

Comment: I think the only difference is that the `acf` plot starts at lag 0 and the `ggAcf` at lag 1.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/57574/90705 This might be the solution to your problem ;-)

Comment: That's actually the answer I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[stats.stackexchange.com/a/57574/90705](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/57574/90705) Here's the answer to it. It wasn't actually a problem with the functions :), just a different specification on the functions